# Modify Twilio sample code to attach voicemail recoding and send by email

Tags: node.js, twilio, sendgrid, email-attachments

The following post from Twilio explains how to write and implement a function for sending the link of a recorded message to email.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/forward-voicemail-recordings-to-email

I want to attach to the voicemail recording rather than just send the link. Here is my attempt at modifying their code. Unfortunately it's causing a 500 error. I'm not very experience with NodeJS so perhaps you can help.

Dependencies for `SendGrid` and `FS` are included and this function worked perfectly until I modified it with `FS`, `pathToAttachment`, attachment variables and the attachments array.

```
//Initialize SendGrid Mail Client
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

//FileSystem
const fs = require("fs");

// Define Handler function required for all Twilio Functions
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    
pathToAttachment = `${event.RecordingUrl}`;
attachment = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString("base64");

// Build SG mail request
sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_SECRET);
        // Define message params
        const msg = {
          to: context.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
          from: context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
          fromname: 'Voicemail',
          text: `URL is: ${event.RecordingUrl}`,
          subject: `${event.From} (${event.country} / ${event.lang})`,
          attachments: [
            {
                content: attachment,
                filename: "Voicemail.wav",
                disposition: "attachment"
            }
          ]
        };
        // Send message
        sgMail.send(msg)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Neat.")
            callback();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Not neat.")
            callback(err);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you modify the code from the Twilio blog:

**Forward Voicemail Recordings to Email w/ Studio, Functions, & SendGrid**
https://www.twilio.com/blog/forward-voicemail-recordings-to-email

.. to **attach** the email recording instead of link to it and how to add a **from name** as well as a from email address.

```
const request = require('request');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
    const fileUrl = event.RecordingUrl;
  
    // Build SG mail request
    sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_SECRET);

    request.get({ uri: fileUrl, encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => {
    
        const msg = {
            to: context.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            from: {
                "email": context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                "name": `My company`
            },
            text: `Attached voicemail from ${event.From}.`,
            subject: `${event.From}`,
            attachments: [
                {
                    content: body.toString('base64'),
                    filename: `MyRecording.wav`,
                    type: response.headers['content-type']
                }
            ]
        };
        // Send message
        sgMail.send(msg)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Neat.")
            callback();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Not neat.")
            callback(err);
        });
    });
};
```

This is how you modify the code from